# How to convert `ros::Time` to string while keeping the UNIX format?

Tags: c++, ros, unix-timestamp

**Context:**
I have image files with UNIX timestamps as their names, e.g. `1341846314.694004.png`. The names correspond to the message `header.stamp` of the ROS .bag-file that publishes the images.
Using Python I generated bounding box files for each image and used the same pattern to name them, e.g. `1341846314.694004_bb.txt`.

**Problem:**
I am unable to convert the `header.stamp`, that is of type `ros::Time` and of format UNIX time, to string in C++.

*Every resource that I read so far, tells me to either use `header.stamp.toSec()` (which does not help as relevant information is being lost), or to convert it to some other time format from which I then, in turn, would be able to convert to string (which again does not help as I need the UNIX format).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time classes provides fields for secs and nsecs both in [Python](https://docs.ros.org/en/diamondback/api/rospy/html/rospy.rostime.Time-class.html) and [C++](http://docs.ros.org/en/diamondback/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1Time-members.html). So you can use them and combine them to a string:

**Python:**

```
stamp = rospy.Time.now()
print(str(stamp.secs) + '.' + str(stamp.nsecs))
```

**C++:**

```
ros::Time stamp = ros::Time::now();
std::stringstream ss;
ss << stamp.sec << "." << stamp.nsec;
std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
```

The output for both implementations is like:

> 1612707880.149451971